# set of all monoid homomorphisms $(\mathbb N_0, +) \to M$

Tags: abstract-algebra, monoid

Let $M$ be a monoid. Determine the set of all monoid homomorphisms $(\mathbb N_0, +) \to M$.

I know that for a monoid homomorphism the following has to be true:

1. $f(a\circ b) = f(a) \ast f(b)$
2. $f(e) = e$

Here, $\circ = +$ on the natural numbers and $\ast$ is not explicitly given. $e$ is the identity element.

Now, if for example $\ast = \cdot$, so the basic multiplication, then the function $f: x \mapsto e^x$ would be such a homomorphism. $f(a+b) = f(a) \cdot f(b)$ would be $e^{a+b} = e^a \cdot e^b$ with $e^0 = 1$ which is true because $0$ is the identity element for $+$ and $1$ is the identity element for $\cdot$ .

But because $*$ is not explicitly given, how to find the monoid homomorphisms?

Answer (score 3):

It is sufficient to know where $1$ is sent to. After that, one has $f(0)=e, f(n) = f(1+1+\cdots+1) = f(1)^n$ for any monoid homomorphism $f$. This shows that $f(1)$ determines $f$ totally. Next, given any $m\in M$, let $f_m\colon\mathbb{N}\to M$ be given by $f_m(0)=0, f_m(n) = m^n$. Then there is a function $\varphi$ from the monoid $M$ to the set $\text{Hom}_{\text{Mon}}(\mathbb{N}, M)$ of monoid homomorphisms from the naturals to $M$, given by $\varphi(m) = f_m$. Conversely, there is the evaluation function $\varepsilon$ from $\text{Hom}_{\text{Mon}}(\mathbb{N}, M)$ to $M$, given by $\varepsilon(f) = f(1)$. Starting with any $m\in M$, we have $(\varepsilon\circ\varphi)(m) = f_m(1) = m$, and similarly $(\varphi\circ\varepsilon)(f)=\varphi(f(1))=f_{f(1)}=f$ for any $f\in\text{Hom}_{\text{Mon}}(\mathbb{N}, M)$. Thus, there is a bijection between those. If you want to do some extra, you can show that $\text{Hom}_{\text{Mon}}(\mathbb{N}, M)$ is actually a monoid under $f_m\cdot f_n = f_{m\cdot n}$, and then $\varphi$ is an isomorphism of monoids.

Comment: You were faster than me by 50 seconds...

Comment: @J.-E.Pin seems like that! $(\ ^\circ\smile^\smile)$

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the asnwers! If I understand it correctly, any monoid homomorphism $f$ which satisfies $f(n) = f(e)^n$ where $e$ is the identity element in $M$, is the set which I'm looking for?

Comment: @syphracos nope, you misunderstand a bit. $f$ takes natural numbers as its input and the identity element for those is $0$ (under addition, ofc!), and that is sent to $e\in M$ always. What you are interested in is $f(1)\in M$, and this is the one that determines $f$.

Comment: Okay, so let me start again. The fact that I have a monoid homomorphism tells me that $f(0) = e$, where $0$ is the identity element for the naturals and $e$ is the identity element in $M$. From this condition, for any natural number $n$ the homomorphism $f$ will act on the element $1 \in M$. So this is the part $f(n) = f(1)^n$. It always acts on $1$ but $n$ tells us how many times. Am I correct with this?

Comment: @syphracos I think you still got it wrong. You know by definition that $f(a+b)=f(a)\cdot f(b)$ for any natural numbers $a, b$, so now write any $n$ as the sum of $n$ copies of $1$. This gives you $f(n)=f(1)^n$. $1$ is a natural number, not an element of $M$, while $f(1)\in M$.

Comment: Yes, sorry! Of course, $1 \in \mathbb N_0$ and $f(1) \in M$

Comment: @syphracos now it looks good! $(\ ^\circ\smile^\circ)$

Comment: So, by having $f(n) = f(1)^n$, the homomorphism $f$ always acts only on the number $1 \in \mathbb N_0$. But $n$ then in some sense determines the value $f(1)$ by taking $f(1) \circ f(1) \circ .... \circ f(1)$ $n$ times. Right?
Maybe the part "always acts only on the number $1$ " is a little bit wrong defined by me, but by that I mean on the right hand side I will always have $f(1)$

Comment: @syphracos I don't know what you mean by it "acting" on something, but its all values are determined by the assignment of $f(1)$. You can put any natural number $n$ into $f$, not just $1$, and you will then get $f(1)^n$ as the value because of the fact you are dealing with a monoid homomorphism. It is not the composite, however, because $M$ need not be $\mathbb{N}$ and then you can't compose $f$ with itself! It is just operating $f(1)$ with itself inside $M$ sufficiently many times.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to express what I mean exactly, but nevertheless, I understand now the part $f(n) = f(1)^n$. Is it then accurate to say that the set of all monoid homomorphisms $F$ contains exactly those $f$ which satisfy $f(n) = f(1)^n$ ?

Comment: @syphracos That is kind of enough, but doesn't actually describe the set at all. The bijection between the set of such homomorphisms and $M$ is what you are actually after.

Comment: That's the part with $f_m$ from your answer right? I'm still trying to understand it..
And why do you have $f_m (0) = 0$ ?

Comment: @syphracos yes it is that part indeed. We always have $f_m(0)=e$ because every $f_m$ is a monoid homomorphism and must send identity to identity. $f_m$ is just the morphism with $f(n)=m^n$ and in particular $f(1)=m$.

Answer (score 3):

Such a homomorphism is completely characterised by $f(1)$. Using a multiplicative notation for the monoid $M$, one gets
$f(0) = e$ by definition and $f(n) = f(1)^n$ since $n = \underbrace{1 + \dotsm + 1}_{\text{$n$ times}}$.